# datagrid get selected cell subtract with textbox

Tags: c#, linq

im trying to select a cell from the datagrid (columns are ticket and time of movie) and subtract the number of tickets using a textbox, at the minute im able to subtract all the tickets but i want to subtract the one the user selects (im using wpf and linq from database)

```
private void CompleteBooking_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        //string current = (string)DvgFilmTime.SelectedItem;

        var query = from x in db.FilmDetails select x;
        foreach (var x in query)
        {
            x.Tickets -= Convert.ToInt32(tbxTicket.Text);
        }
        db.SubmitChanges();
        MessageBox.Show("Booking Completed");
     }
     catch (Exception)
     {
        MessageBox.Show("Error please select a number");
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, information provided is not sufficient for exact code. But assuming that `DataGrid`'s `ItemsSource` contains collection of `FilmDetail` object, you can try cast `SelectedItem` to `FilmDetail` instead of `String` as you seems have tried.

Then use unique property value of `FilmDetail` (the primary key, `DetailId` for example), to match and update corresponding row in database :

```
if(DvgFilmTime.SelectedItem != null)
{
    FilmDetail current = (FilmDetail)DvgFilmTime.SelectedItem;

    var filmDetail = (from x in db.FilmDetails 
                      where x.DetailId == current.DetailId
                      select x).FirstOrDefault();
    if(filmDetail != null)
    {
        filmDetail.Tickets -= Convert.ToInt32(tbxTicket.Text);
        db.SubmitChanges();
        MessageBox.Show("Booking Completed");
    } 
}
```